# Creating Instance Group Manager fails without Editor role on service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam, gce-instance-group

I've got a node.js application trying to create an Instance Group Manager. It's running on an instance with a service account attached to the instance with scopes `compute-rw` and `cloud-platform`. This service account has a role with the following permissions:

```
includedPermissions:
- compute.autoscalers.create
- compute.autoscalers.get
- compute.disks.create
- compute.images.get
- compute.images.useReadOnly
- compute.instanceGroupManagers.create
- compute.instanceGroupManagers.get
- compute.instanceGroupManagers.use
- compute.instanceTemplates.create
- compute.instanceTemplates.get
- compute.instanceTemplates.useReadOnly
- compute.instances.create
- compute.instances.setMetadata
- compute.instances.setTags
- compute.networks.get
- compute.subnetworks.get
- compute.subnetworks.use
```

Looking at the audit log for `resource.type="gce_instance_group_manager"` I can see in first log entry:

```
ProtoPayload.authorizationInfo:
  - granted: true
    permission: compute.instanceGroupManagers.create
    resourceAttributes:
      name: projects/my-project/zones/us-east1-b/instanceGroupManagers/resource-name
      service: compute
      type: compute.instanceGroupManagers
  - granted: true
    permission: compute.instanceTemplates.useReadOnly
    resourceAttributes:
      name: projects/my-project/global/instanceTemplates/resource-name
      service: compute
      type: compute.instanceTemplates
  - granted: true
    permission: compute.instances.create
    resourceAttributes:
      name: projects/my-project/zones/us-east1-b/instances/resource-name-0000
      service: compute
      type: compute.instances
  - granted: true
    permission: compute.disks.create
    resourceAttributes:
      name: projects/my-project/zones/us-east1-b/disks/resource-name-0000
      service: compute
      type: compute.disks
  - granted: true
    permission: compute.images.useReadOnly
    resourceAttributes:
      name: projects/my-project/global/images/resource-name-image
      service: compute
      type: compute.images
  - granted: true
    permission: compute.subnetworks.use
    resourceAttributes:
      name: projects/my-project/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/resource-name-subnet
      service: compute
      type: compute.subnetworks
  - granted: true
    permission: compute.instances.setMetadata
    resourceAttributes:
      name: projects/my-project/zones/us-east1-b/instances/resource-name-0000
      service: compute
      type: compute.instances
  - granted: true
    permission: compute.instances.setTags
    resourceAttributes:
      name: projects/my-project/zones/us-east1-b/instances/resource-name-0000
      service: compute
      type: compute.instances
```

I get 200 OK back with `status: "PENDING"` in body.

Only when looking through the audit logs do I see a log entry with `status.message: INVALID_PARAMETER` with no explanation and then another log entry with:

```
jsonPayload.error:
  - code: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_DENIED
    detail_message: ''
    location: ''
```

When attaching the Editor role to the service account I can create the Instance Group Manager so there seem to be some permissions missing. The logs show no permissions that were not granted so what could be missing?

[Raw logs](https://hastebin.com/amufaxejic.pl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the instanceTemplate attached service accounts to the instances. Because of that `iam.serviceAccountUser` role is required on the service account used by the instance creating the instance group manager.

In my case the service accounts are not needed so I removed it from the instance template and the permissions above work.